# Raster issue with ArcGIS SDK for Javascript

Tags: javascript, sdk, widget, raster, arcgis

I am coding a website using the ArcGIS SDK with Javascript and using the Timeslider Widget.  The code I am using is below, which brings up the Timeslider just fine, shows the correct date, and 2 minute time frame I would expect.  I press play and it seems to run fine but I am not seeing the raster displayed at all.

```js
    // time slider widget initialization
            const timeSlider = new TimeSlider({
                container: "timeSlider",
                view: view,
                timeVisible: true, // show the time stamps on the timeslider
                loop: true});
```

As a note, I am using this exact same raster file in the Web App Builder with the Time Slider Widget and it works fine.  So a bit uncertain what may be happening.

I see an error in the console that reads as follows:

**"Tile 13,3196,1328 layer 1/1 error [message]: unsupported lerc version 2.6"**

Does anyone happen to know what may be causing this or how best to resolve?

Thank you!